# customError in web.config only works on .aspx pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

I am using FriendlyUrl which gets rid off all .aspx extensions. However, when I set customError in my web.config file it only works if the error is caused on a path with .aspx extension.

Ex that does **not** go to my own error-page:
`localhost:xxxxx/DefaultMissSpelled`

Ex that goes to my own error-page:
`localhost:xxxxx/DefaultMissSpelled.aspx`

I actually have to manually add the `.aspx` to get it to work, or I just get the default asp.net error-page.

Web.config:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="Errors/DefaultError.aspx" mode="On">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="Errors/Filenotfound.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

(I have tried with and without .aspx extension inside web.config).

Comment: is this inside `<system.webServer>` or `<system.web>` tag ? if you are using IIS 7 or later use ` <system.webServer>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="Redirect" path="/page-not-found"/>
</httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

change the path name with your friendly url

and this is for IIS 6

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/internal-server-error"/>
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/page-not-found"/>
</customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks for asnwer, is it fine using both `system.web` and `system.webServer` in same web.config file?

Comment: Yes, it is. it is totally depends on the version of IIS that you are using and it will pick up the one which is appropriate for your hosting server application.